# Get alert - Activemq camel

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

**My Application:** Consumer of activemq is already running so it will consume if there is message in Activemq and process it.

I want to get alert If there is any failure in my logic. First I try to re delivery my message 3 times if there is any failure in my logic and then send to `DLQ`, after 3 times re delivery I want to get alert by mail. I have done code to send mail by click a `sendMail.bat` file. I have consumer code in java, now I want to run `sendMail.bat` file before the message go to `DLQ`. This is code I have in bean.xml.

```
<!-- here we configure our DeadLetterChannel -->
<bean id="myDeadLetterErrorHandler" class="org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder">
    <property name="deadLetterUri" value="activemq:queue:ThermalMap.DLQ"/>
   <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="myRedeliveryPolicyConfig"/>
</bean>

<!-- here we set the redelivery settings -->
<bean id="myRedeliveryPolicyConfig" class="org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryPolicy">
    <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="3"/>
    <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="250"/>
</bean>

<camelContext id="activeContext1" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route startupOrder="1" errorHandlerRef="myDeadLetterErrorHandler">
        <from uri="activemq:queue:ThermalMap"/>
        <transacted/>
        <to uri="bean:msgPro1?Method=Processor1"/>
    </route>
 </camelContext>
```

Let us assume am going to run `sendMail.bat` file from java application. so am going to create one more java(TriggerMail.class) file in my application(ActivemqCamel) and execute my `sendMail.bat`. I don't know where to link this `TriggerMail.class` in my bean.xml? Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you currently send your failed messages to *activemq:queue:ThermalMap.DLQ* what you could do is

change the deadLetterUri of your errorHandler to *activemq:queue:ThermalMap.TMP*,

then create a simple route that would

- consume message from *activemq:queue:ThermalMap.TMP*,
- send an email
- and then send the message to *activemq:queue:ThermalMap.DLQ*

I'm sure there are plenty of other ways to accomplish what you want.